# Updating classnames according to checkbox status

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple rows, each having it's own checkbox. I have the following script to invert all checkboxes:

```
$("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if (this.checked == false) {
        this.checked = true;
    } else {
        this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

Now, I want that each row (it has it's unique ID - like `id='row1'` `id='row2'` etc etc) to have their classnames changed: if the checkbox is going to be checked it should change to `class1` else to `class2`.

How would this be done? I'm new to jQuery so I have no idea how I would get the element ID or something. I don't know how to match the checkbox with the row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a side note you can just do `this.checked = !this.checked`to invert the checkboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the row where the checkbox is in:

```
$("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    var toRemove = this.checked ? 'class1' : 'class2',
        toAdd = this.checked ? 'class2' : 'class1';

    $(this).closest('tr').add(toAdd).remove(toRemove);
    this.checked = !this.checked;
});
```

*(there are other ways to avoid repeating the class names, but they become less readable)*

If the classes are initially set correctly, you can also just use [`.toggleClass()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$("INPUT[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    this.checked = !this.checked;
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('class1 class2');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Your last code worked perfectly since my classes are set correctly.

Comment: @Devator: See also my update how to simplify the `if - else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/sPgGp/

Example here.

Comment: Thank you, got it already but still thanks for your time / answer.